# Secure Ajax with Flash

Tags: ajax, security, jquery, flash

In order to secure Ajax requests, [Ran Bar-Zik sugested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193825/how-can-i-better-protect-my-php-jquery-ajax-requests-from-malicious-users) to "create a small flash file to receive the data, SALT it and encrypt it with MD5. Than sent it to the server. The attacker is able to see the data but it is encrypted." Does anybody who has done this would want to share the code with the world? Thanks :-)

Comment: By the way,  md5 is a message digest algorithm,  it is not a method of encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr Ran Bar-Zik is mistaken.   The security system he has proposed violates [CWE-602](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html) and is "(in)[security though obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)".

In short the problem is that the server is providing data to a client side application.  The client can do whatever he pleases. He can modify the javascript code or intercept and modify all communications using TamperData or Burp Proxy.  A flash application can be decompiled and any secrets stored in memory can be obtained with a debugger like [ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/). **There is no solution to this problem.**

Comment: @Roger like i said.  there is no solution to this problem.   the Internet doesn't work like this, and hopefully it never will.

Comment: There always a solution, brother. And always a way to find a problem. But thank you. "No" is also an answer. :-)