# protect ajax & jquery injection

Tags: jquery, ajax, code-injection

How can I protect against injection? (jQuery & ajax)

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" /> 
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" /> 

var name = $("#name").val();
var mail = $("#email").val();
```

Output:

```
$("#logga").html('Name: <b>' + name + ' </b>Comment:<b> ' + comment + '</b>');
```

Comment: What kind of injection?

Comment: use OAuth to protect web services.

Comment: A common thing developers protect themselves against is PHP mysql (or other database) injection. Here are some discussions: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043303/php-mysql-injection-protection) [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Mitigation) [tizag](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php). Perhaps this is what you are wondering about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no way to secure data with JavaScript**. because all the code in the client side code is available to the attacker.

But you would have some form of **authentication** so that only genuine requests from your application returned data;

prefer to read :[How can I better protect my php, jquery, ajax requests from malicious users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193825/how-can-i-better-protect-my-php-jquery-ajax-requests-from-malicious-users)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that the name/email contents are escaped properly for display, you can run them through `.text` first or create nodes and append their values with `.textContent`.

```
var name = document.createElement('span');
name.textContent = $("#name").val();
$("#logga").html("Name: <b>" + name.textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, that the user couldn't damage the produced html code? Then you'll need to escape the html entities:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Output line:

```
$("#logga").html('Name: <b>' + htmlEntities(name) + ' </b>Comment:<b> ' + htmlEntities(comment) + '</b>');
```