# AJAX fake data, security ways

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am terrible about AJAX data post, You know AJAX is client side and can be changed by user, For example I have AJAX request with data id=1 , if user try to change this value and send request, how can i detect the fake value, edited by user?

Comment: Use CSRF token or pass some headers keys.

Comment: Hello Himanshu thank you, i will learn this, do you know any other tips

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195038/4248328

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I better protect my php, jquery, ajax requests from malicious users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193825/how-can-i-better-protect-my-php-jquery-ajax-requests-from-malicious-users)

Comment: @HalidKyazim, the links shared with above comments will give you other ways. :-)